# HTML and CSS - Small set of codes to show ecommerce deals

Tags: html, css, wordpress, web, e-commerce

I have no knowledge of coding. I have to show shopping deals in html and css in my site.

I have to show:

1. Deals Title
2. Merchant Logo/any image
3. Description if any
4. 4.Expiry date if any
5. 5.Buy Now/Activate deal button

I have picked random screen shots [Demo 1](http://prntscr.com/eaelc4), [Demo 4](http://prntscr.com/eaenq6)

Comment: SO isn't a code writing service. It's a place to find solutions to specific problems. Start here - http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: Yes, I know, I am stuck here. And I am finding solutions for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a simple example:

```css
    .pos{
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 99;
        top: 2%;
        width:90%;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>sparroltie</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
<body>


<div class="w3-container  ">

  <div class="w3-card-8 w3-dark-grey " style="width:350px; position:relative">

    <div class="w3-container"  >
      
      <img src="https://i0.wp.com/adiply.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/mobile-product03.png?fit=635%2C530" alt="Avatar" style="width:300px;">
      <h5 class="pos w3-padding-small w3-left">visit our site : Sparrolite.blogspot.in 
      for more tutorial about blog
      </h5>

      <div class="w3-section  w3-center">
        <button class="w3-btn w3-padding-medium w3-green">Get this deal  at 0$</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, but this looks like complete HTML page. I need small piece of codes which can be fitted in WordPress post.